# How to convert a string to a enum?

Tags: powershell, enums

I'm trying to convert a string to a enum value in PowerShell but couldn't find this anywhere...

I'm getting a JSON result, where I only want to consume the Healthstate which is defined as a string.

```
enum HealthState
{
    Invalid = 0
    Ok = 1
    Warning = 2
    Error = 3
    Unknown = 65535
}
$jsonResult = "Ok"
$HealthStateResultEnum = [Enum]::ToObject([HealthState], $jsonResult)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can simply cast the string result as the Enum type:

```
$HealthStateResultEnum = [HealthState]$jsonResult
```

This will work whether `$jsonResult` contains a string or value from the enum type.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to get the value__ of the enum:

```
PS> [Enum]::GetValues([HealthState])|? {$_ -eq $JSonresult}|Select @{n="Name";e={"$_"}},value__

Name value__
---- -------
Ok         1
```

Or simply

```
PS> [int]([HealthState]$jsonResult)
1
```