# Parse enum values by name in VBA

Tags: vba, forms, powershell

I want to write some VBA code that should parse MSForms-constant names (given as a string, like "fmTextAlignLeft") into their actual value. Since there is no native way to do so I was considering to put the name of the constant into a powershell code that will then be executed and return the result.

```
Private Sub ParseEnumByName(EnumConst As String)
    Dim WScript As New WshShell
    Dim PSCode As String
    Dim Result
    PSCode = "(some code)" & EnumConst & "(more code with exit $Value statement)"

    Result = WScript.Run("Powershell -command """ & PSCode & """", 0, True)

    ParseEnumByName = Result
End Sub
```

This should be feasible by iterating through all enums in the MSForms library and get the values out of them with something like
`[System.Enum]::GetNames( [System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle] )` or maybe something like explained here: [How to convert a string to a enum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52889230/how-to-convert-a-string-to-a-enum)

The problem is that the System.Windows.Forms library contains totally different enums and typenames than the MSForms library available in VBA.

I tried to `Add-Type -Path "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\FM20.DLL"` where the MSForms library is stored but it returns an error saying the file or assembly or some related file could not be found.

How may I get a reference to MSForms in Powershell?

**Edit: I have actually found a demi-native way in VBA (Excel VBA only) to solve this issue without passing values to external script hosts. Please see below.**

Comment: Given that the enumerated form MSForms are unlikely to change *that* much, you could just hard-code the values into your program in an array or something. That’s not really going to be much worse than launching an external powershell process and running a script to do the lookups. You could even use the powershell script to *generate* the hard-coded values that you embed into your program.

Comment: See answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the function I figured out. So far it seems to work with all pre-defined enums and constants and also self defined enums in Excel. The function must be placed in a module!

```
Static Function ParseValue(StringValue) As Variant
    Dim ParseValueBuffer As Variant

    If IsEmpty(ParseValueBuffer) Then
        ParseValueBuffer = 1
        Application.Run ("'ParseValue " & StringValue & "'")
        ParseValue = ParseValueBuffer
        ParseValueBuffer = Empty
    Else
        ParseValueBuffer = StringValue
    End If
End Function

Sub TestMe()
    MsgBox "First line" & ParseValue("vbcrlf") & "Second line"
    MsgBox ParseValue("fmTextAlignCenter") 'Should return "2" (if MSForms is referenced)
    MsgBox ParseValue("rgbblue") 'Should return 16711680
End Sub
```

Comment: Works great!
But, only in Excel VBA. Tested in Access VBA - not working